# python- Django : Where does Django "Append a Slash"?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I was wondering about...

If I have an application called **magazine**, and its `urlpatterns` inside `urls.py` is like this :

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

path("articles/<int:pk>", views.get_article, name="article")
```

.. without a trailer slash, then Django should ***"append a slash"*** by default, right?

Where is this slash appended?

I mean is it added only when I handwrite the url in the browser?

I mean if there was an anchor tag in a template like this :

```
<a href="{% url 'magazine:article' 5 %}"> Article 5 </a>
```

.. Wouldn't it go and get the path above without a trailer slash, and then an error with **Not Found**?

Does this **APPEND_SLASH** setting mean that I can't, or it's impossible to reach that link above without adding a trailer slash at the end?

Comment: The slash is not appended. If you set the [**`APPEND_SLASH`** setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-APPEND_SLASH) to `True`, then it will first try to match the URL *without* adding a slash, and only if that fails, it will append a slash and try again to find a match.

Comment: Oh okay , thanks.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slash is *not* appended. It thus means that you can visit this page with `/arcticles/5` for example (to access the article with primary key 5).

Django has an [**`APPEND_SLASH`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash). If this is set to `True` (the default), it will first try to match a path with the given URL patterns, and if that fails, append a slash and search again.

It makes more sense to use a trailing path however, so I would advise to rewrite the path to:

```
path('articles/<int:pk>/', views.get_article, name='article')
```

Comment: Thanks  @Willem Van Onsem